# Windows 7, Boot Session just for gaming?

Tags: windows-7

i was wondering if somebody did this setting? a way to boot your windows session like Safe mode, but Networking and Hardware acceleration enabled, and in this way had a session just for gaming without any other app opened

Comment: What advantage are you hoping to get from this?

Comment: @Toast boost my pc, sometimes i like to speak with TeamSpeak and make streaming in Twitch.tv, while im playing but my current windows session used a lot of my resources such CPU and RAM, cuz i have web server, and other stuff

Comment: This would probably go better on SuperUser anyhow.

Answer (score 5):

Safe Mode doesn't just disable "Networking and Hardware Acceleration".  It turns off virtually all non-essential services, bypasses all on-startup software, and (most importantly, from a gamer's perspective) loads a built-in set of fail-safe drivers from Microsoft.  Your games will not run any better, and in fact will probably run much worse (if they run at all), in such a configuration.

What you should probably do, if you're so inclined to reboot your system just for the sake of game performance, is to install a second copy of Windows onto another partition or a secondary internal hard drive.  Then, install nothing but your essential drivers and game software on that partition.  When you've booted to your secondary OS, *nothing* from the primary will be able to take any resources from your games.

You should of course bear in mind that, while you're booted into that second partition, your web server "and other stuff" will be unavailable to you and anyone else who may use it.  You will need to reboot the system again to bring those services back up.  Ideally, you should not be playing games on anything that's acting as a server unless you are the only user of that server and are willing to accept the risks involved.

Answer (score 0):

start > run > [msconfig](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2292)

Comment: I love the irony of using an Apple support document for a Windows configuration issue.

Comment: Best support doc on the front page of google.  Too bad about downvotes; it's a 100% legitimate answer to his question, complete with documentation.

Comment: @Toast The down votes are probably because if you removed the link, this doesn't answer the question. You should try to provide a bit more detail in the answer itself. as of right now if the link died this wouldn't answer the question.

Comment: Sadly, that's the most detail I can give w/out more information.  Since it's a server, I'm not comfortable saying "Stop all processes that aren't XYZ".  Server configuration/maintenance is a complex beast, and the best way to solve any problem is to RTFM.